# Spring @ConfigurationProperties not populated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I am experiencing problems using the @ConfigurationProperties feature.
Probably, I am missing something, since the mechanism seems very simple, but for me, it does not work.

I am using Spring Boot with the following main Application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueuesProperties.class)
@PropertySource("file:config/queues.properties")
@ImportResource("classpath:/spring-config.xml")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

with QueuesProperties

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "wmq.in.queue")
public class QueuesProperties {
   private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueuesProperties.class);

   private String descr;

   public String getDescr() {
      return descr;
   }

   public void setDescr(String descr) {
      this.descr = descr;
   }
}
```

The properties file is very simple (I am trying to isolate the problem)

```
wmq.in.queue.descr = description
```

Then, I am trying to @Autowired the QueuesProperties in a @Component that I use in a spring-integration flow with a .
The QueuesProperties  is correctly injected but the `descr` attribute is null.

```
@Autowired
private QueuesProperties queuesConfiguration;
```

while this

```
@Value("${wmq.in.queue.descr}")
private String descr;
```

is correctly evaluated.

I have made a lot of attempt with different configurations or code, but the result is the same. I get the QueuesProperties bean but it is not populated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question isn't very clear if the `wmq.in.queue.descr = description` properties is written in applciation.properties file. I said it because you say that the properties is correctly evaluated with `@Value` and not with

```
@Autowired
private QueuesProperties queuesConfiguration;
```

Even the `@PropertySource("file:config/queues.properties")` let me to think that probably the your `wmq.in.queue.descr = description` properties isn't written in applciation.properties but in file:config/queues.properties.

Summing
For use `@ConfigurationProperties` feature you have write the properties in application.properties and use `@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueuesProperties.class)` on @Component, @Configuration and so on annotated classes like below.

```
@Component
@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueuesProperties.class)
public class YourBean {
 ....

private final QueuesProperties queuesProperties;

public YourBean(QueuesProperties queuesProperties){
     this.queuesProperties = queuesProperties;
}


.....


}
```

actually you can change the application.properties file name customizing spring boot properties evaluation but for your local app I discourage. I consider application.properties a good name for naming a place in which you put the configuration properties of your application

I hope that it can help you

Comment: I have an application.properties file (actually they are 2, one with the defaults in the classpath and one with the overrides in the file:config/application.properties), and I also tried to load from properties in the external one, but now I am trying to isolate the problem and I added another properties file (file:config/queues.properties) with only one property
`wmq.in.queue.descr = description`

Comment: do you annotate the configuration/component class with @EnableConfigurationProperties as in my sample?

Comment: I annotated the Application class with 
@EnableConfigurationProperties(QueuesProperties.class) and @PropertySource("file:config/queues.properties")

Comment: but @EnableConfigurationProperties  must present on the class that use it and not on the Application.class

Comment: Tried adding it to the @Component where I use it (and then, almost everywhere), but it's not working.
I think I will end up creating a brand new project in order to test only this feature. Maybe some overlapping configurations are preventing the bean from being populated.

Comment: Currently I decided to implement another solution, manually loading a properties file old-style

`File file = new File(QUEUES_CONFIG_FILE_LOCATION);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        try {
            properties.load(new FileInputStream(file));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new BeansException("cannot load queues configuration", ex) {};
        }`

I don't like it, but I was running out of time and I needed to make it work.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm struggling since days with the exact same issue